# React Native insert into state variable of nested array

Tags: react-native

I am deep cloning a state variable, inserting an object into one of its array subfields, and setting the value of the state variable to the clone using useState():

```
clone = _.cloneDeep(comments);
clone[i].comment.replies.push(message.replace(/^[@A-Za-z_0-9]+[\s]/, ''));
setComments(clone);
```

This doesn't do anything. How do I properly insert into a state variable?

Answer (score 0):

What ended up working for me was the following: `clone = comments.map((x)=>JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(x)));`